# how to compute individual RSS value as percent of total RSS?

Tags: statistics

If I have:
$$\mathsf{total} = x_1 + x_2 + x_3,$$
I can compute the percent of total occupied by $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ as 
\begin{gather*}
p_{x_1} = 100\% \frac{x_1}{\mathsf{total}}\\
p_{x_2} = 100\% \frac{x_2}{\mathsf{total}}\\
p_{x_3} = 100\% \frac{x_3}{\mathsf{total}}
\end{gather*}
such that
$$p_{x_1} + p_{x_2} + p_{x_3} = 100\%.$$

However, if I have a root-sum-of-squared total:
$$\mathsf{totalRSS} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$$
and I know $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, how can I compute (similarly) the percent of $\mathsf{totalRSS}$ occupied by $x_1$ (e.g., $s_{x_1}$) and separately $x_2$ and $x_3$, such that:
$$s_{x_1}+s_{x_2}+s_{x_3} = 100\%?$$
That is, how to compute $s_{x_1}$?

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't:
$$s_{x_1} = 100\% \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}}{\mathsf{totalRSS}}\right)$$

UPDATE:

Trying to give some context... let's say:

1. xi = the RMS noise voltage in a signal due to an i'th random noise source (where the example above has 3 independent noise sources; e.g. i=1,2,3)
2. totalRSS = the total RMS noise voltage (e.g. combine all i random noise sources into one clean signal and observe the output).

What is the contribution of the i'th random noise source to the total noise observed?

What kind of number can be computed to give a meaningful answer to this question?

Comment: Thanks for nice edits @dfeuer

Comment: It is formatted better, but it's still just as vague as ever. You say there's some physical meaning you're after. Please describe the physics/engineering/care-of-pet-rats context so we can give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally these kinds of sum-of-square fractional contributions are computed without the square-root on the total, for example you can look up "explained variance" $R^2$ for regression.

So if you define your total quantity to be

$$y = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$$

without the square root, then the contribution from $x_1$ for example would be

$$x_1^2 / y$$

and these contributions would be percentages that add up to $100\%$.

Comment: Thanks @user2566092. Perhaps you're right. However, I'm working with real data and the value for `sqrt(y)` has a physical meaning, as do the values for `x1` (etc.). I'd like to show the percent contribution of `x1` to `sqrt(y)`. The problem with computing `x1*x1/y` as a percent is I don't know the physical meaning of that value. Do you?

Comment: @user88502: you haven't given any information about the context; we're left guessing at what you want with only "no, that's not it" when we get it wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that @dfeuer. I'm trying to find `x1_pct`, `x2_pct`, and `x3_pct` (where, for example, `x1_pct` is the percent contribution of `x1` to `totalRSS`) such that, `x1_pct+x2_pct+x3_pct=100%`. Is that an ill-defined question? Let me know if something is missing in the description. I know the values for `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.

Comment: @user88502: it is ill-defined. You have not explained to us how we could check whether a potential answer is valid.

Comment: @user88502: I doubt you can do better than user2566092's suggestion.

Comment: I added an Update in the original posting. If I compute @user2566092 value of `x1^2/y`, what is its physical meaning a layman can understand? Is `100*x1^2/y` the variance of x1 as a percent y (which, y itself, is a variance in my model)? Or, some other explanation?